# How to use with relationship to model param in controller method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Normally I can use   `CustomerAddress::with(["province", "city", "district"]);` to include relationship to the response but I use the model as method params like below:

```
public function show(CustomerAddress $address)
{
    return $address;
}
```

Currently, I can get a query with relationship using:

```
public function show(CustomerAddress $address)
{
    $address = CustomerAddress::with(["province", "city", "postalcode", "district"])->where("id", $address->id)->firstOrFail();
    return $address;
}
```

But I think it's will make a double query, which bad for performance. My another solution is don't call Model in the param like below:

```
public function show($address_id)
{
    $address = CustomerAddress::with(["province", "city", "postalcode", "district"])->where("id", $address_id)->firstOrFail();

   return $address;
}
```

But for some reason, I need to use `CustomerAddress` model in method params. Is any other solution to include relation to `$address` without call model class again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the model loaded, so you only need to load the relations. This is called [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

```
public function show(CustomerAddress $address)
{
    return $address->load("province", "city", "postalcode", "district");
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The show method like this

```
public function show(CustomerAddress $address) { 
return $address::with(["province", "city", "postalcode", "district"])->where("id", $address->id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

And you can use the show method and pass the `CustomerAddress` as argument

```
show(new CustomerAddress())
```